# Ant pathconvert task with multiple map

Tags: ant, dictionary

I have a requirement where I have to convert my Java classes residing under C:\temp\java\com\abc\def\xyz directory to **com.abc.def.xyz.[ClassNameWithoutDOTClass]** within ANT script.

I have written following in ANT;

```
<property name="build.ws.java.dir" value="C:\temp\java" />
<for param="wsClass" >
    <path>
        <fileset dir="${build.ws.java.dir}" includes="**${file.separator}**WS.class" />
    </path>
    <sequential>
        <path id="java.ws.class" >
            <fileset file="@{wsClass}" />
        </path>
        <echo message="Actual wsClass = ${toString:java.ws.class}" />
        <pathconvert property="trimmed.wsClass" refid="java.ws.class" >
            <map from="${build.ws.java.dir}${file.separator}" to="" />
            <map from=".class" to="" />
            <map from="${file.separator}" to="." />
        </pathconvert>
        <echo message="Trimmed wsClass = ${trimmed.wsClass}" />
    </sequential>
</for>
```

It should work BUT I am getting following result (which is incorrect);

```
 [echo] Actual wsClass = C:\temp\java\com\abc\def\xyz\DummyServiceWS.class
 [echo] Trimmed wsClass = com\abc\def\xyz\DummyServiceWS.class
```

I am expecting something like '**com.abc.def.xyz.DummyServiceWS**'. Can anyone point out what am I missing?

Thanks,

--

SJunejo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I have found a way by using advance mapper options and in this case I used **[packagemapper]**. So my updated script is like;

```
<pathconvert property="trimmed.wsClass" refid="java.ws.class" >
    <packagemapper from="${build.ws.java.dir}${file.separator}*.class" to="*"/>
</pathconvert>
```

And above is returning correct value as follows;

```
[echo] Actual wsClass = C:\temp\java\com\abc\def\xyz\DummyServiceWS.class
[echo] Trimmed wsClass = com.abc.def.xyz.DummyServiceWS
```

Hope this helps,

--

SJunejo

Answer (score 0):

Quote from the [pathconvert manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html):

> **Note:** The map elements are applied in the order specified, and only the first matching map element is applied. So, the ordering of your map elements can be important, if any from values are prefixes of other from values.

This means the since the first mapping matched, the others were ignored.  You need to specify three separate pathconvert tasks, one working on the result of the previous one.